# C# starting remote service on a virtual machine

Tags: c#, service, virtual-machine, servicecontroller

I have a host that runs several virtual machines, on every virtual machine runs a service wich works fine locally but when i try to execute it remote from the host i get accces denied.
i have searched google for a while now, impersonate doesnt work because the host account is very different than the virtual machine accounts.
i use the folowing code to start the remote service.

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ExecuterService", "servername");
sc.Start(id);
```

now my question is: is there a way to authenticate my C# app so it can start the remote service by for example just giving in the user credentials for that machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remotely control a Windows Service with ServiceController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996282/how-to-remotely-control-a-windows-service-with-servicecontroller) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581931/starting-remote-windows-services-with-servicecontroller-and-impersonation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the host application have correct access rights, then you could workaround and use process call to NET console comands:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("NET", "start ExecuterService");
Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
p.WaitForExit();
```

But it is ugly.